# What architecture is best for multiple users editing the same database record?

Tags: django-rest-framework, architecture, webrtc, google-docs, saas

I have a Django REST Application that has POST and GET endpoints for a record in database. It allows multiple users to POST data to it and GET from it. I can implement locking to make sure the records don't get overwritten and I can make sure the front-end pulls latest record first before users starts to write.

The problem comes when two users are editing the same thing simultaneously, I am looking for a solution as robust as Miro or Google Docs, where you can see the name of the user editing a line while you are also editing the same line.

Currently, its a simple Django REST app but is there anything out there that can help me make it more like Google Doc editing, as robust and truly realtime as it?

How are they managing such a thing in their architecture? What am I missing here?

Comment: If you are talking about the DB records, then use transaction in the request to ensure all commits are made at the same time. If you are talking about showing in real-time who is editing, then look in the direction of websockets

Comment: Please ask this question in [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) forum. This is not a programming question :).